# How to create 4 random defined percentages that sum 1

Tags: r

I'm doing a college project and I need to create for random numbers that sum 1. The problem I'm having is that i need two values to be between 0.2 and 0.5 (each one), other to be between 0.15 and 0.4 and the last one to be between 0.15 and 0.3. I'm new to R so I don't think this is the correct way. Thanks for your help

I've tried using a bunch of whiles with the conditions but it creates an infinite loop and not the values I wanted

Comment: It would be best to show your attempts. It's easier to help you fix something than to start from scratch. These requirements seem tricky to satisfy with a truly "random" number generator.

Comment: ... though it is trivial to repeat random sampling of numbers until your conditions are met. Inefficient, yes, but it might be much easier in the long run than trying to devise an algorithm that will *with certainty* give you what you want. (It'd be a fun exercise if I didn't have 17.3 tons of work on my desk.)

Comment: Ooh, @JuliusVainora, why did you delete it? I couldn't find a hole in the logic (I was trying :-), is it because this is homework and you made it too easy?

Comment: @r2evans, because that solution didn't fully take into account the restriction on upper limits.

Comment: Huh. I ran it 1M times and found no errors, are you certain it could fail?

Comment: Taking `x <- c(0, 0, 0, 0.01)` the last element becomes 0.45 > 0.3.

Comment: You could just create the 4 values within each range using `runif`.  Then normalize them and see if the results stay within the desired range.  This would require loops to create the random vals and then check the normalized values using a function if you want to repeat the process.

Comment: @JuliusVainora, I'd think a simple approach would be use your math up-front, but place it in a loop to check constraints. It's not ideal, but much much better than a completely-stochastic filter.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies and sorry for the bad post, it was my first one i"l do it better next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

```
ll <- c(0.2, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15)
ul <- c(0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3)
```

where `ll` and `ul` correspond to lower and upper limits for each of the random variables. Next,

```
x <- runif(length(ll), 0, ul - ll)
```

is a vector of uniform random draws from intervals [0,0.3], [0,0.3], [0,0.25], and [0,0.15]. The reason for this is that our final vector is

```
if(sum(x) > 1 - sum(ll)) {
  ll + x / sum(x) * (1 - sum(ll))
} else {
  ll + x + (ul - ll - x) / sum(ul - ll - x) * (1 - sum(x) - sum(ll))
}
# [1] 0.3112532 0.2927185 0.2347163 0.1613119
```

So, if `sum(x) > 1 - sum(ll)`, this means that `x` is too large. In that case we renormalize it by making it smaller. In this way all the constraints are satisfied. Otherwise, `x` is too small. In that case we are going to add a portion of `ul - ll - x`. Now the key is that necessarily

```
sum(ul - ll - x) > (1 - sum(x) - sum(ll))
```

which means that `ul - ll - x` doesn't get increased and, hence, again all the restrictions are satisfied.

Kernel densities of the respective elements are as follows

[image]